# How to get different color/fill/opacity when hovering over PNG images with SVG coding

Tags: html, svg

I'm a bit rusty, not doing much in HTML for a decade or so. I bought a template to use for my photography website and it works to my liking. However I'm working on a separate part that addresses my images of the USA. Having used an AREA MAP for choosing specific states in the past I run into the problem that when the image resized the clickable parts did too. I managed to get that working with SVG, which is new to me. So far so good. To make it even better I would like to change the color/opacity/fill when someone is hovering over a certain state. It would like this so nothing happens when hovering over a state I haven't images off, but it would when it does contains image. To make it simple I made this test page: https://www.states.nl/TEST4.html to show what I mean. Only "Montana" is currently added. Of course I looked first on the internet but everything I thought that could work didn't. Does somebody know how to get this working for me? Thanks in advance!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title><br>
</head>

<body>

<script>#backing {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#backing svg { 
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}
          </script>
        <figure id='backing'>
          <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1200 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
            <image width="1200" height="800" xlink:href="http://www.states.nl/img/locations/usa_map.png"></image>
            <a xlink:href="/MT_relief.html" target="_parent">
                <polygon id="Montana" points="238,38,253,41,259,41,259,42,265,42,265,43,272,43,303,48,311,48,353,54,363,54,363,55,372,55,372,56,382,56,382,57,392,57,392,58,401,58,401,59,411,59,411,60,421,60,421,61,433,61,433,62,448,62,448,63,475,64,465,180,427,179,416,179,392,178,392,177,356,175,356,174,346,174,346,173,336,173,336,172,306,169,305,170,303,181,301,179,299,179,297,176,288,177,288,176,286,176,286,175,275,176,275,175,273,175,273,174,271,174,271,173,263,167,261,158,260,158,260,156,257,154,257,152,255,151,254,146,253,146,253,144,252,144,251,141,244,140,243,132,243,128,244,128,246,124,248,124,249,115,242,111,241,106,240,106,240,104,239,104,238,95,234,92,234,90,233,90,234,81,232,80,234,64" fill="#fff" opacity="0"/><title>Montana</title>
            </a>
          </svg>
        </figure>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: `<script>` should be `<style>`

Comment: Also, it will help if you provided links to what sources you thought would help

Comment: @Rojo Thanks for that, I appreciate it!

The sources I tried where either not for images like GIF or PNG and had PATH instead of IMG in the code. I also read it wouldn't be possible with images. I was hoping I could address the "fill" tag or "opacity" tag when hovering over it. Still not sure if that is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PNG has nothing to do with the solution, it is a background image.

You have to make the :hover over the Montana polygon work:

```html
<style>
  svg {
    height: 300px;
    background:grey;
  }
</style>
<svg viewBox="0 0 1200 800">
  <style>
    polygon {
      pointer-events: all;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    polygon:hover {
      fill: hotpink;
    }
  </style>
  <image href="//www.states.nl/img/locations/usa_map.png"></image>
  <a href="/MT_relief.html" target="_parent">
    <polygon id="Montana" points="238,38,253,41,259,41,259,42,265,42,265,43,272,43,303,48,311,48,353,54,363,54,363,55,372,55,372,56,382,56,382,57,392,57,392,58,401,58,401,59,411,59,411,60,421,60,421,61,433,61,433,62,448,62,448,63,475,64,465,180,427,179,416,179,392,178,392,177,356,175,356,174,346,174,346,173,336,173,336,172,306,169,305,170,303,181,301,179,299,179,297,176,288,177,288,176,286,176,286,175,275,176,275,175,273,175,273,174,271,174,271,173,263,167,261,158,260,158,260,156,257,154,257,152,255,151,254,146,253,146,253,144,252,144,251,141,244,140,243,132,243,128,244,128,246,124,248,124,249,115,242,111,241,106,240,106,240,104,239,104,238,95,234,92,234,90,233,90,234,81,232,80,234,64" fill="none"></polygon>
    <title>Montana</title>
  </a>
</svg>
```

And once you have the polygons for all States, you don't need the background image. Just set the fill color for every State.

Appeltje.. eitje..

Comment: Didn't realize help was that close... ;-) Appeltje.. eitje.. so it seems, but not for that guy that learned from the HTML 3 and 4 books long ago. LOL But never too old to learn.